# Woocomerce: missing invoice and recover them

Tags: woocommerce

I have a problem, from a mistake I deleted 5 invoices, and I need to recover them, and put them in the same place. How can I do this?

Comment: Reload from backup? You *do* have backup, right?

Comment: I have one, but how should I recover it from the backup, cuz I did a lot of changes on the platform

Comment: Worst case you could always reload the backup to a clean DB, extract the required lines, and import it into the real DB. To be sure, and not make the situation worse, I'd also have a fresh backup of the DB ready at hand... (Of course, depending on the schema, this might be a quite tedious task, it might involve several tables...)